# what's the reason to get this error in React js - TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React js and I am trying to fetch data from API and I am getting all data in this.state but while displaying in dropdown I am getting an above error. Please go through the code and let me know where I went wrong.

Json data:

```
{
   "status":true,
   "message":"Success",
   "data":{
      "id":37,
      "pan_no":"12345",
      "pan_name":"abhishek",
      "pan_front_image":"C:\\fakepath\\download.jpg",
      "customer_image":"C:\\fakepath\\download.jpg",
      "document_type":"Driving License",
      "document_front_image":"C:\\fakepath\\download.jpg",
      "document_back_image":"C:\\fakepath\\download.jpg",
      "bank_name":"ada",
      "account_no":"12345",
      "confirmed_acc_no":"12345",
      "ifsc_code":"MITM2250451",
      "account_holder_name":"fasfdas",
      "phone_no":"1234567890",
      "nick_name":"213123"
   }
}
```

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: [],
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8003/api/kyc/")
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }));
        // .catch(()=>this.setState({hasErrors:true}));
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return ( <div>
            <div class = "ab-info-con" >
            <h4> Menu </h4> 
            <select> {
                this.state.data.map((obj) => { <
                    option value = { obj.id } > { obj.pan_no } </option>
                })
            } </select> 
            </div> 
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: data is not an array, but an object, is it right?

Comment: i have done with other ways as well but still getting the same  error

Comment: @Max is correct, your JSON response is an object, not an array, so trying to call the non-existent map method fails with an error.

Comment: Try to console your response and share that here.

Comment: @Abhishek you need to check for negative case also, render will get called immediately after the component is mounted by then your API might have not return the data yet. so check for the negative case

Comment: @Max yes it is in object form

Comment: @UmeshMGowda, I have checked, API is returning data

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same thing???

Comment: any suggestion from anyone

Comment: @Abhishek but why are you using `map()` on data that has only one record? there is only one `id` and one `pan_no`, your data example is bad or your solution is bad, as it would generate only one option for that data even if it would work and making a `select` with one option seems to irrational.

Answer (score 0):

The error is being thrown because `.map` is an array method and you are calling it on an object. From the structure of your response and your code, I can guess that what you should do is this.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Home extends Component {

      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            id: '',
            panNo: ''
        };
      }
      
      componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8003/api/kyc/")
        .then(results=>results.json())
        .then(data=>this.setState({ id: data.data.id, panNo: data.data.pan_no }));
        // .catch(()=>this.setState({hasErrors:true}));
      }
      
      render(){
        
        return (
            <div>
              <div class="ab-info-con">
                <h4>Menu</h4>
                <select>
                  {
                    <option value={this.state.id}>{this.state.panNo}</option>
                  }</select>
              </div>
            </div>
           
        )
      }
    }



export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8003/api/kyc/")
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }));
        // .catch(()=>this.setState({hasErrors:true}));
    }

    renderOptions = () => {
        const { data } = this.state;
        let options = [];
        if (typeof data !== "undefined") {
            if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
                for (const property in data) {
                    options.push(<option value={property.id}>{property.pan_no}</option>)
                }
            }
        }
        return options;
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
            <div>
                <div class="ab-info-con">
                    <h4>Menu</h4>
                    <select>
                        {this.renderOptions()}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

try this, i have added the empty check before looping the data.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: @Abhishek can you share the error message.

Comment: @Abhishek added undefined check try now

Comment: error is removed but data is not coming in a select tag

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't need mapping at all, as you are having only one record. To get the `id` and `panNo` you should use `this.state.data.data.id` and `this.state.data.data.panNo`.

If you would need to use `map()` on an object, I would suggest using `Object.keys`:

Instead of this:

```
        <select> {
            this.state.data.map((obj) => { <
                option value = { obj.id } > { obj.pan_no } </option>
            })
        } </select>
```

Use this (doesn't make sense with this data structure, only to show the idea):

```
        <select> {
            Object.keys(this.state.data).map((obj) => { if(obj == 'data'){ <
                option value = { this.state.data[obj].id } > { this.state.data[obj].pan_no } </option>
            }})
        } </select>
```